# with a frequency vs at a frequency

Tags: prepositions

I was told I should use **with**. Can you explain why it is incorrect to use **at**? Or, **at** is also correct?

The chart shows the frequency **with/at** which people in the USA ate in fast-food outlets between 2003 and 2013.

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is an explanation other than that 'with a frequency of...' is what we say.

Comment: @KateBunting, thank you but according to ngram, "at a frequency" is actually more common. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+a+frequency%2Cwith+a+frequency+&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3

Comment: True, but _at a frequency_ mostly refers to sound waves and radio waves. We use _with_ when _frequency_ has the sense 'how often something happens'.

Comment: It could also be worded this way: The chart shows the frequency of eating at...." or "...the frequency of dining at fast-food restaurants...."

Comment: @user8356, thank you. So like **with a frequency**, **frequency of** also means how often something happens? Only **at a frequency** refers to sound and radio waves?

Comment: It is common in scientific concepts to use "at" with a frequency: "The emission line of this element is at 453 nanometers". But, I see nothing wrong with "The chart shows the frequency at which people ate at fast food restaurants..." The shortest wording would be something like, "Chart of fast-food dining frequency of/by/for USA residents." It's not unusual for more than one preposition to make sense in some expressions, while some expressions seem to always use just one preposition. We sing "Happy Birthday to you", but it would not really be incorrect to sing "Happy Birthday for you!"

Comment: For the two senses of _frequency_, see [this](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/frequency). I was pointing out that most of the results for **at** produced by your Ngram were expressions like 'this happens at a frequency of 200 Hz'.